# Are there any tools to check values in tx validation?

Tags: development

Are there any developing tools that can show values(like the hash of tx to sign or the stack of script execution) in tx validation so that developers can check the correctness of their validation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the hash of the tx to sign, I am not aware, but you can easily remove signatures, place the output script, adopt the length field(s), and hash yourself?

For script execution, there are several debuggers: [here](http://paulkernfeld.com/bse/) and [here](https://webbtc.com/script/2bb5d0ac0eb17f5ebe2d660ec47b4888943b4a4f5433c09bd6514b7a36859a95:0) and [here](http://bitcoin-script-debugger.visvirial.com) :-)